# Android - ScrollView doesn't show all contents

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollview

I'm developing an Android Application where I need to use scroll view . I tried some way and the scroll view is working and doesn't show all the contents.

Here is the code snippets I used.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/lower"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/exitButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:background="@drawable/exitselector" >
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/editTextContentLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ctbimLogo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/login_logo" >
                </ImageView>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/userName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/username"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="User name" >
                </EditText>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/passWord"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/password"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="password"
                    android:inputType="textWebPassword" >
                </EditText>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/loginButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/loginbuttonselector" >
                </Button>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/lower"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this xml code below which will not hide the content. 
Using `RelativeLayout` you must specify the below and above of the view then only you will get full view without hiding it.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exitButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@id/header" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/editTextContentLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ctbimLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ImageView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="User name" >
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passWord"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="password"
            android:inputType="textWebPassword" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/lower"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/exitButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/exitselector" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
     <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/editTextContentLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ctbimLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/login_logo" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/username"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="User name" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passWord"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/password"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="password"
            android:inputType="textWebPassword" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/loginbuttonselector" />
    </LinearLayout>


   </ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/lower"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```